# Yii session timed out but some controllers are still accessible. How to send the user to the login page

Tags: php, session, yii, yii-components

I am using Yii 1.10 and there is an issue with the session. If a user who is logged in leaves his system for some time Yii detects it and destroys the session,
In that case user should not be able to access any controller or any action of a any controller.
But in my case some controllers are still accessible and they are showing me the results. Which is not good.
Please suggest that what should I do to prevent the accessible, I am doing something wrong please help me to get out of it.

Comment: What are you doing at the moment to prevent usage of your controllers/actions. Are you checking if the user is still logged in?

Comment: @Evil_skunk If I will start checking the session each time then I will need to check it on every action to check that if user is logged in or not.
I want to check in the controller class or where I will be checking once,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in yii way, You should use [access control filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter). It basically check if current user have access to requested controller action.

It should be sufficient for simple use case. For complex cases, you should use RBAC. You can get more detail about how to use RBAC in yii [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like this:

in your Module.php

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action) {
        if (parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)) {
            $controller->layout = 'admin_dashboard';
            if(empty(Yii::app()->session['admin_id']) || empty($_SESSION['admin_id'])){
                unset($_SESSION);
                Yii::app()->user->logout();
            }
            $route = strtolower ($controller->id . '/' . $action->id);
            //Add those page which not requires authentication like: 'action/controller',
            $publicPages = array(

            );
            if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && !in_array($route, $publicPages)){
                Yii::app()->getModule('admin')->user->loginRequired();
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        } else
            return false;
    }
```